# Three forward slashes for block commenting?

Tags: c++

First noticed this in Notepad++, where `//` comments and `///` comments were shown in different colours.

[Doxygen](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/sdk/native-client-sdk-coding-guidelines/documenting-classes-using-doxygen-style-comments) revealed more about it, but I'm not convinced about its efficacy.

1. Why would anyone use the three slashing commenting style when it's far easier to type `/*` and `*/`? (*I figure there has to be a better explanation than it being useful when nesting comments*)
2. For it to be usable, do editors support block commenting for triple slashes in the way that Visual Studio has support for `Ctrl+k Ctrl+c` for multi-line comments?

Comment: Are you using Doxygen? This is more of why Doxygen recommends `///` instead of `/* */` for C++ code documentation.

Comment: It would be `/** */` for documentation.

Comment: Ok, so it's for documentation. I thought it was an alternative/better way of doing multi-line comments.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Visual Studio the `///` indicates [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc998489.aspx) not just comments.  Following your link the explanation is the same.  It is used to adorn comments that will be specifically formatted via your editor or some other tool as documentation for a class, method, namespace, etc.

Comment: This is less Visual Studio and more C# specific. C++ in Visual Studio obviously can have `///` comments, but they have no special meaning, and the doc-comment-viewer will show `//` or `/* */` comments as well.

Comment: I still do not get it.
I want to comment e.g. a function such, that when my mouse is over it, my comment would be visible or in the menu, when u can choose class functions. How to do that?

Comment: Does there exists any shortcut for documenting? It's boring to create 3 `/` all the time. Ctrl + K creates 2 `/`, not 3..

Comment: @Arkady I don't really understand what 'boring' means in this case. If you create a single line with 3 '///' when you hit enter for a new line, the new line will also begin with 3 '///' slashes.

Comment: @linuxuser27 wow, that's not happening with my settings, i.e. I need to type '///' by hands on each line. How to set it up?

Comment: @Arkady are you working in a C# or C++ project? The C# project will automatically add the `///` each new line in a comment. In C++ it does not add slashes for a new line. Note that the C++ language service specifically recognizes the `///` when in a C++ project since C++/CLI can generate .NET documentation. For C# the `///` is a part of the documentation mechanism.

Comment: I'm working with C++, and can't find such option :( even if `///` is recognizable.

Comment: @Arkady There is no option. This isn't something that the editor provides - hence no option. It is a part of the language service that provides the nice comment formatting. Basically, I am sorry if this wasn't clear, but there is no option other than the `//` slash comment keystroke in C++. In C# it automatically adds `///` each new line.

Comment: @linuxuser27, thank you. I've found that Poco Project (it's amazing C++ library) has very nice comments under each class and function, widely using `///`. According to fact, that their code has highest level of readability, in my own chart :), I was going to use their code formatting notation. And thus was wondering that I can't find shortcut for `///` in VS.

Comment: Current link is obsolete, a newer link *for C#* is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/documentation-comments

Answer (score 10):

The author might intend to put documentation after ///

At where I work, we use 3 styles of doxygen comment blocks for documentation because lack of coding style guidelines.

1. ///
2. //!
3. /**   */

Answer (score 5):

1. Surely, its easier to hit the same key thrice than hitting two separate keys.
2. Don't know about other IDEs, but XCode4 supports code snippets where you can type pretty much anything. On Visual Studio, I use Visual Assist X, which gives me the same thing. [XCode4 Example](http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/easy-doxygen-code-snippets-for-xcode-4/),[Visual AssistX example](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/vasnippets.asp). I'd have to assume other IDEs provide similar functionality.

That said, yes I have come across triple slashes too and they are generally used to indicate comments that an auto-documentation system like doxygen would pick.

Comment: Visual Assist X also has the extend-multiline-comments option, which used with snippets makes the `/**  *  */` comments take almost no work.

Answer (score 1):

in C# /// will actually override the variables hover text for example

```
///<summary>
/// This method is for executing some test code.
///<summary>
public void SomeMethod() {}
```

while in another class file or deeper in a class you can hover over the method, class, or static variable and it will give a tool tip stating what is in summary