# C++ difference between '//' and '///'

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Why in Code::Blocks at least '///' is dark blue and '//' is blue? and i have seen in some source codes that sometimes they use '///' and other times '//'.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187616/three-forward-slashes-for-block-commenting .

Answer (score 7):

It means nothing to C++, its the same as the traditional `//`. The
`///` is typically used for documentation.
For codeblocks, it triggers a highlighting mode for [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)..

```
// Normal comment
/// Doxygen comment
//! Doxygen comment

/*! Doxygen comment block */
```

Answer (score 4):

For the C++ compiler both are just comments.

But, source code documentation tools like *doxygen* might handle them in different ways.

Example:

- `///` -> special comment block, eg: function documentation
- `//` -> standard comment

`///` tells *doxygen* that this comment shall be part of the generated documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no distinction inherent to C++.

It's just a style choice, possibly carried over from other languages, or from an unrelated tool.

Notepad++ makes `// comments` non-bold but `/* comments */` bold. Same story: style choice.

Answer (score 1):

Code can be commented in such a way as to produce documentation.

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html is one system and some IDEs identify that this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools that use comments to add met-information not used by the compiler but by tools.

For example [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) uses special comments style to annotate code for the production of high-quality documentation automatically.

Answer (score 1):

/// is a documentation comment, there should be something in Code::Blocks documentation that describes it, but for example, you  would use /// before a function  deceleration to document what it does, but use a // for non-documentation (e.g. General remarks, commenting out code ...)

Note: I haven't used Code::Blocks but   I'm assuming it is like most other C++ ides that support documentation comments