# What does /// do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was adding some comments to my code using Notepad++, and instead of typing `//check for null` I accidentally typed `///check for null`. I noticed that this caused my text to be colored differently, so presumably it has a different function. When I tried to Google it, Google seemed to replace my `javascript ///` with just `javascript`.

So, my question: **What does /// do in JavaScript?**

Also, this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187616/three-forward-slashes-for-block-commenting) because that question is about C++, I'm talking about Javascript.

Comment: The first two slashes start a comment, and the third slash is part of the comment. So basically nothing at all; it's just a comment. If Notepad++ does something weird, that's its problem.

Comment: @Pointy should just make that the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Three forward slashes for block commenting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187616/three-forward-slashes-for-block-commenting)

Comment: @pointy hmm, okay. seems odd that notepad++ has it weird though.

Comment: Are you sure the language syntax setting is on JavaScript in notepad++? I cannot reproduce it, `///` and `//` both give me same colours.

Comment: As @Pointy wrote is just a comment. Sometime you can mark a comment to find it later. Maybe Notepad++ is wrong and detect it as a regular expression!

Comment: @charlietfl yeah.. so it didn't actually give me an error, that was from a different part of my code. So I guess /// is just a comment with a /. Also, should I delete this question now?

Comment: @Denny it turns from light green to cyan. Yes it is on javascript.

Comment: No, part of the point of the site is to provide a reference for others who will search for problems in the future, so don't delete when you have the answer you want.

Comment: @pydude nevermind, it also colours for me, didn't notice it at first

Comment: There are "literate programming" environments" which treat triple slashes specially. JSDoc supports triple slashes as documentation comments with the help of a special plugin. TypeScript uses triple slashes as a way to reference `.d.ts` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything special in Javascript. `//` is a comment, and anything after it until a line break is just part of the comment.

Notepad++ displays it differently because apparently in C#-land `///` is used for writing documentation in comments that appears in Intellisense - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187616/three-forward-slashes-for-block-commenting) answer, and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5916/why-are-comment-blocks-important) one too. So Notepad++ treats them different, and still does this in Javascript mode for some reason.

As for Google, it strips special characters like `/` from searches these days.