# Why can my comment consist of so much forward slash (/)?

Tags: c++, comments

I know that there are many types of comment, I will list out a few of them (those related):

- `//` - Normal comment
- `///` - This would make the comment **bold**

And surprisingly, the IDE would not raise an error in this code (Even it is not executed, it should still control the programmer somewhere):

```
/////////////////// HI!
```

Why would the standard allow this to happen?

BTW, my **IDE is Code::Blocks 20.03** if it matters.

Comment: "This would make the comment bold" That's probably a feature of your IDE. The C++ standard doesn't have any idea of what font is being used to display programmers' source code. As for your other question, the compiler considers everything between the `//` and the newline to be all part of the comment, all equally disregarded.

Comment: `///` is used by systems like Doxygen to denote comments that are part of inline documentation. Your IDE may bold these because they are inherently special for a practice that is used widely in industry.

Comment: Comments are not "executed" in some way. That's what makes them comments. If they get executed they won't be comments any more.

Comment: Regarding "make the comment **bold**": [Three forward slashes for block commenting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187616/)

Comment: *"Why would the standard allow this to happen?"* -- why would the standard go out of its way to forbid this to happen? That is, why do you think this should be an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the C++ standard: [lex.comment](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.comment)

> The characters `//` start a comment, which terminates immediately before the next new-line character.

From the above, you can infer that every character (other than newline) which follows the first two `/` characters is part of the comment.

If that wasn't already clear enough, it goes on to note:

> The comment characters `//`, `/*`, and `*/` have no special meaning within a `//` comment and are treated just like other characters.